# How can I structure my express app where I only need to open a mongodb connection once?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**Note: Please read the edited portion of this post before answering, it might save you time and answers one of my questions.**

The problem I'm having is pretty simple but I'm pretty new to this overall and I'm having issues figuring out how to implement a mongodb database connection properly in a node/express app.

I'm using express 3.x and am basing my app layout around this project supplied by the author of Express:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/d8caf209e38a214cb90b11ed59fd15b717b3f9bc/examples/blog (now removed from repo)

I have no interest in making a blog however the way the app is structured appears to be quite nice. The routes are separated and everything is organized nicely.

My problem is I might have 5-6 different route js files and each route js file might have anywhere between 1 and 15 routes; of those routes 1 or 15 might want to access the db.

So my problem is it seems like a really terrible idea to do a db.open(...) every single time I want to query the db. I should mention at this point I'm using the native mongo-db driver (npm install mongodb).

I would also need to include a file like this:
http://pastebin.com/VzFsPyax

...in all of those route files and all of my model files. Then I'm also dealing with dozens upon dozens of open connections.

Is there a way I can structure my app in such a way where I only make 1 connection and it stays open for the duration of the session (having a new one made every request would be bad too)?

If so, how can I do this? If you know the answer please post a code sample using tj's blog app (the one linked earlier in this post) structure as a base guide. Basically have a way where the routes and models can use the db freely while being in separate files than the db open code.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I made some progress on solving one of my issues. If you look at tj's blog example he initializes his routes in the app.js like so:

```
require('./routes/site')(app);
require('./routes/post')(app);
```

And in the routes js file it starts like this:

```
module.exports = function(app){
```

I stumbled on a project earlier today where I saw someone pass 2 variables in the modules.exports call -> function(app, db). Then figured wow could it be that easy, do I need to just adjust my routes to be (app, db) too? Yeah, it seems so.

So now part 1 of the problem is solved. I don't have to require a mongo.js file with the connection boilerplate in every route file. At the same time it's flexible enough where I can decide to pick and choose which route files pass a db reference. This is standard and has no downside right?

Part 2 of the problem (the important one unfortunately) still exists though.

How can I bypass having to do a db.open(...) around every query I make and ideally only make a connection once per session?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1946211

Comment: How does that help my situation, can you elaborate a bit on what's going on with your code?

Comment: It opens one connection per collection.

Comment: So it's normal for me to write the db.open(...) callback nest each time I make a query? This may end up happening 100+ times in an average sized web app.

Comment: I don't know whether it's normal, the code I showed above doesn't do so.

Comment: What happens if I want to query 2 different collections, would I need to require the mongo.js file twice?

Also, what's going on with the setTimeOut() in the "with-mongo.js" example?

Comment: updated https://gist.github.com/1946211, now using a single database connection (with a connection pool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really silly. In the documentation it seems like db.open requires to be wrapped around whatever is using it, but in reality you can use it without a callback.

So the answer is to just do a db.open() in your database connection module, app.js file or where ever you decide to setup your db server/connection.

As long as you pass a reference to the db in the files using it, you'll have access to an "opened" db connection ready to be queried.

Comment: Note: I won't mark myself as correct just yet because perhaps there's caveats associated to doing this (performance issues?). Maybe a MongoDB expert can chime in!

Comment: How do you get the db object if not as a parameter of the callback function?

Comment: MongoClient.open() returns null (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#open) so does MongoClient.connect() (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect). This answers doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 16):

Other solution is to pass database to the router via request, like this:

**app.js**

```
var db = openDatabase();

var app = express();

app.all('*', function(request, response, next)
    {
    request.database = db;
    next();
    });

app.get('/api/user/:id', Users.getByID);
```

**users.js**

```
var Users =
    {
    getByID: function(request, response)
        {
        request.database.collection('users').findOne(...)
        response.send(user);
        }
    };

module.exports = Users;
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but shouldn't app.js -> app.all -> request.database = db; ?  (vs. request.database = database)...?

Comment: How to make the openDatabase function synchronous? I know there are some other module like mongoskin and monk but they ship with some other problems.

Answer (score 3):

I made a very simple module [hub](https://github.com/baryshev/hub) for this case that replaces the use of a global space.

In app.js you can create db connection once:

```js
var hub = require('hub');
hub.db = new Db('foobar', new Server('10.0.2.15', 27017, {}), {native_parser: false});
```

And use it from any other files:

```js
var hub = require('hub');
// hub.db - here link to db connection
```

This method uses a feature of 'require'. Module is only loaded for the first time and all the other calls gets a reference to an already loaded instance.

**UPDATE**

That's what I mean:

In main file like app.js we create Db connection, open it and store into hub:

app.js:

```js
var hub = require('hub');
hub.mongodb = require('mongodb');
hub.mongodbClient = new hub.mongodb.Db('foobar', new hub.mongodb.Server('10.0.2.15', 27017, {}), {native_parser: false});
hub.mongodbClient.open(function(error) {
    console.log('opened');
});
```

Now in any other file (message for example) we have access to opened connection and can simple use it:

message.js:

```js
var hub = require('hub');
var collection = new hub.mongodb.Collection(hub.mongodbClient, 'message');

module.exports.count = function(cb) {
    collection.count({}, function(err, count) {
        cb(err, count);
    });
};
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing now. I have a mongo.js file with 3 lines (setup the db), and then I require it in the routes/models where I'm using it.

The problem is every time I want to use the db I have to wrap a db.open(...) around the query I want to use.

Comment: @Rayons really? It simple and it works. Your variants? What way to access shared resources (like DB connections, configurations, locale strings) from different modules are you using?

Comment: @Vadim
Check what I added to my question under "edit". Wouldn't this eliminate the need for hub or any type of redundant requiring?

Comment: No reason for @Raynos comment. Whether you would use this approach or not there's nothing wrong with Vadim sharing this example.